# Centering ImageView using JavaFX

Tags: java, image, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to center an ImageView in a JavaFX GUI. However, the image just appears in the top left corner of the window.
My code:

```
FlowPane picPane = new FlowPane();
Image photo = new Image(url, 300, 300, false, false);
ImageView myView = new ImageView(photo);
picPane.getChildren().add(myView);
picPane.setColumnHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
```

Comment: The [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) gives an overview of all the layout panes. `FlowPane` is probably not what you need here.

Answer (score 1):

The property "columnHalignment" is ignored for horizontal flowpanes (default settings).

Take a look at the HBox Layout. There you can specify the alignment properly.

EDIT: some code:

```
public HBox addHBox(URL url) {
    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    hbox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
    hbox.setSpacing(10);
    hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");
    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    Image photo = new Image(url, 300, 300, false, false);
    ImageView myView = new ImageView(photo);

    hbox.getChildren().add(myView);

    return hbox;
}
```

I am very sorry. I cannot test it at the moment. But it should work this way.

Comment: @StackOverflown added some code. I cannot test the code at the moment. I'm very sorry. Just try it and if it is not working, feel free to post a comment here. I will take a look at it later.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution I found.

```
Image img = new Image( "file:"+ imgURL );                
imgViewer.setImage(img);
centerImage(imgViewer); // this does the centering..


public static void centerImage(ImageView imgView) {
        Image img = imgView.getImage();

        if (img != null) {
            double w = 0;
            double h = 0;

            double ratioX = imgView.getFitWidth() / img.getWidth();
            double ratioY = imgView.getFitHeight() / img.getHeight();

            double reducCoeff = 0;
            if(ratioX >= ratioY) {
                reducCoeff = ratioY;
            } else {
                reducCoeff = ratioX;
            }

            w = img.getWidth() * reducCoeff;
            h = img.getHeight() * reducCoeff;

            imgView.setX((imgView.getFitWidth() - w) / 2);
            imgView.setY((imgView.getFitHeight() - h) / 2);

        }
    }
```

Just modified from this link's solution a little: [Centering an image in an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32781362/centering-an-image-in-an-imageview)

Answer (score -4):

Your Image object sits in myview,
myview sits in picPain.
picPain is centered, however its' contents are not centered in terms of "drawing" with the image holder Graphics object!

The component drawing is myview.
Second, the size of the container myview requires measuring on each side from the container picPain.
While containers have alignments of their internal contents "they have defaults for their sizing and position they draw from the top left corner".
Set them and calculate them!

Comment: _Set them and calculate them!_ no, (nearly) never in client code - that's the task of an appropriate layout pane