# Centering an image in an ImageView

Tags: imageview, javafx-8

I am currently trying to center an image in an ImageView using JavaFX.

So I load the image in the view :

```java
Image img = new Image("...");
imageView.setImage(img);
```

and let's suppose the image is huge (2000x3000) and not the ImageView (400x100)

The rendered image will be aligned on the left, and I would like to put in the center of the ImageView :

[image]

Is there anyway to perform that ?

Comment: Can you post some code on how you are setting the size of the ImageView? If possible, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am fitting to the parent's size : `imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(((AnchorPane)imageView.getParent()).widthProperty());` (same goes for height of course). I can't post a MCVE at the moment, I'm in a rush, sorry ...

Comment: The problem is likely caused by your layout, not by the image view itself, but it's impossible to tell without a [MCVE].

Comment: Actually, using the `setX()` and `setY()` methods I can center it. So I added a listener on the ImageView size, and when it changes, the image centers itself. But it is taking so much time, I was wondering if there wasn't something like `image.center()` (I'm new to JavaFX)

Comment: `setX()` and `setY()` probably don't do quite what you think they do. No-one will be able to help you unless you post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, after days of calculation, I managed to find a good way to do it.

I post it here in case of someone would like to achieve it.

I created a method that only needs access to the imageView :

```java
public void centerImage() {
        Image img = imageView.getImage();
        if (img != null) {
            double w = 0;
            double h = 0;

            double ratioX = imageView.getFitWidth() / img.getWidth();
            double ratioY = imageView.getFitHeight() / img.getHeight();

            double reducCoeff = 0;
            if(ratioX >= ratioY) {
                reducCoeff = ratioY;
            } else {
                reducCoeff = ratioX;
            }

            w = img.getWidth() * reducCoeff;
            h = img.getHeight() * reducCoeff;

            imageView.setX((imageView.getFitWidth() - w) / 2);
            imageView.setY((imageView.getFitHeight() - h) / 2);

        }
    }
```

Comment: In my case I ended up using `setTranslateX` and `setTranslateY` to make it work. I also needed `Platform.runLater(() -> centerImageInImageView(gameImageView));` to make it work in my case - without it the widths/heights were 0, resulting in no translation.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example code that might be a solution for your case:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Image image = new Image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/Frankenstein's_monster_(Boris_Karloff).jpg");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(image);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView.setFitWidth(400);
        imageView.setFitHeight(300);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setPrefSize(400, 300);
        pane.setCenter(imageView);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

Image img = new Image("...");
imageView imgView = new imageView(img);

HBox hbxImg = new HBox();
hbxImg.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
hbxImg.getChildren().add(imgView);
```

That'll put an image in an empty HBox you can align to the horizontal center of the canvas.